# why pydantic from_orm is calling database

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, pydantic

I am using sqlalchemy and pydantic in fast api application. I have orm queries using join. When using `from_orm` from pydantic , it is calling database again. I confirmed via enabling sqlalchemy logs.

#### Original problem

```py
sub_query = (
    db.query(DB_Model_1.id).filter_by(**rule_filter).subquery()
)
rows = (
    db.query(DB_Model_1, DB_Model_2)
    .join(DB_Model_2, DB_Model_2.rule_id == DB_Model_1.id)
    .filter(DB_Model_1.id.in_(sub_query))
    .all()
)
db.commit()
```

```py
# Sqlalchemy db model

ModelBase = declarative_base()

@declarative_mixin
class TimestampMixin:
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())


class DB_Model_1(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'DB_MODEL_1'
    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    c_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False)

class DB_Model_2(ModelBase, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'DB_MODEL_2'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    rule_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(DB_Model_1.id), nullable=False)

# pydantic model
class PydanticModel_1(BaseModel):
    id: int
    c_id: uuid.UUID

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class PydanticModel_2(DateMixin):
    uuid: uuid.UUID
    id: int
    rule_id: int
    time_frame_start: Optional[datetime]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

The rows returned by the above query is the list of tuples in form (DB_Model_2, DB_Model_1), so
When doing

```
rule = PydanticModel_2.from_orm(rows[0][0])
```

this calls database again. I am unable to figure out why.

#### Another case

I debugged it and found that even on single table query, the from_orm is calling database

```py
row = (
        db.query(DB_Model_2)
        .filter(DB_Model_2.rule_id == some_id)
        .order_by(DB_Model_2.created_at.desc())
        .limit(1)
        .all()
    )
    db.commit()
```

When calling on `PydanticModel_2.from_orm(row)` on above, it is calling database again.
However, If i change the query as

```
row = (
        db.query(*inspect(DB_Model_2).attrs)
        .filter(DB_Model_2.rule_id == some_id)
        .order_by(DB_Model_2.created_at.desc())
        .limit(1)
        .all()
    )
    db.commit()
```

(added *inspect(DB_Model_2).attrs )

and then calling from_orm on it, It does not call database again.

#### Logs for ref of join query

```bash
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|SELECT db_model_1.id AS notification_rule_id, db_model_1.c_id AS notification_rule_c_id, db_model_1.user_id AS notification_rule_user_id, db_model_1.purpose AS notification_rule_purpose, db_model_1.targets AS notification_rule_targets, db_model_1.frequency AS notification_rule_frequency, db_model_1.send_at AS notification_rule_send_at, db_model_1.rule AS notification_rule_rule, db_model_1.active AS notification_rule_active, db_model_1.created_at AS notification_rule_created_at, db_model_1.last_run_at AS notification_rule_last_run_at, db_model_1.scheduled_next_run AS notification_rule_scheduled_next_run, db_model_1.status AS notification_rule_status, db_model_1.task_id AS notification_rule_task_id, notification.created_at AS notification_created_at, notification.updated_at AS notification_updated_at, notification.id AS notification_id, notification.uuid AS notification_uuid, notification.rule_id AS notification_rule_id_1, notification.status AS notification_status, notification.time_frame_start AS notification_time_frame_start
FROM db_model_1 JOIN db_model_2 ON db_model_1.id = db_model_2.rule_id
WHERE db_model_2.status IN (%(status_1_1)s, %(status_1_2)s) AND db_model_1.id IN (SELECT anon_1.id
FROM (SELECT db_model_1.id AS id
FROM db_model_1
WHERE db_model_1.c_id = %(c_id_1)s) AS anon_1) ORDER BY db_model_2.id DESC
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|[generated in 0.00036s] {'c_id_1': UUID('74b46d04-e8c5-4ab9-a466-9721b4bd8e4c'), 'status_1_1': <NotificationStatus.SENT: 'SENT'>, 'status_1_2': <NotificationStatus.DELIVERED: 'DELIVERED'>}
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|COMMIT
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|SELECT db_model_1.id AS notification_rule_id, db_model_1.c_id AS notification_rule_c_id, db_model_1.user_id AS notification_rule_user_id, db_model_1.purpose AS notification_rule_purpose, db_model_1.targets AS notification_rule_targets, db_model_1.frequency AS notification_rule_frequency, db_model_1.send_at AS notification_rule_send_at, db_model_1.rule AS notification_rule_rule, db_model_1.active AS notification_rule_active, db_model_1.created_at AS notification_rule_created_at, db_model_1.last_run_at AS notification_rule_last_run_at, db_model_1.scheduled_next_run AS notification_rule_scheduled_next_run, db_model_1.status AS notification_rule_status, db_model_1.task_id AS notification_rule_task_id
FROM db_model_1
WHERE db_model_1.id = %(pk_1)s
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|[generated in 0.00012s] {'pk_1': 2}
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|SELECT db_model_2.created_at AS notification_created_at, db_model_2.updated_at AS notification_updated_at, db_model_2.id AS notification_id, db_model_2.uuid AS notification_uuid, db_model_2.rule_id AS notification_rule_id, db_model_2.status AS notification_status, db_model_2.time_frame_start AS notification_time_frame_start
FROM db_model_2
WHERE db_model_2.id = %(pk_1)s AND db_model_2.uuid = %(pk_2)s
INFO:     2023-06-21 09:49:36|base.py -> _log_info[136]|sqlalchemy.engine.Engine|[generated in 0.00013s] {'pk_1': 5, 'pk_2': UUID('e1b6020d-57c2-4bbc-8c3c-99cdfe3e3a32')}
```

Comment: does your actual `NotificationRule` have only these two columns or more?

Comment: It has more columns. I have just shared minimal example

Comment: are they normal columns or relationships?

Comment: Thanks. I got your confusion. They are just normal column. I have updated the DB models in the question now.

Comment: You didn't include `NotificationModel` or `ModelBase`, so it's rather hard for someone else to say what's triggering the query - but generally additional queries gets triggered for lazy loaded values when the property is accessed (on a relationship/foreign key). To avoid this either change the strategy for how the load is performed (`lazy="joined"`) or don't include the fields. Looking at _what_ query gets invoked will also tell you what is causing the additional load.

Comment: @MatsLindh, they are just normal columns. I have not defined relationships